# How can I export EV3 Classroom app project on Android tablet version of the app?

Tags: ev3

I need to submit EV3 code to enter a coding competition. The program is written in the EV3 Classroom app on a Samsung Android tablet. I tried to look for the file with `.lmsp` extension but cannot find it anywhere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there isn't a way to do this on Android. The SPIKE app has a *SHARE* button on the *My Projects* page but the EV3 app doesn't seem to have this feature.

As an alternative, you could try taking screenshots of the program and submit them.

It may also be possible to find the files using the Android debug program (`adb`), but I couldn't file the files anywhere using a file browser on Android.